# How can I deal with this VSCode error? "remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master."

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to edit my code managed by our GHE repo. The Master branch is protected and requires a pull request be reviewed before being merged into master.

My branch is tracking master so I can pull what others merge.

When I attempt to push my branch I get the following error:

```
> git push origin mybranch:master
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.        
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.        
To github.myghe.com:my-services/my_repo.git
 ! [remote rejected]   mybranch -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.myghe.com:my-services/my_repo.git'
```

When I run the push from the command line without appending `:master`

```
git push origin mybranch
```

It works fine.

How can I get VSCode to push to my branch only and without attempting to update master?